# Are checkboxed items with "use system value" always active?

Tags: magento2

good night guys, I have a doubt I often see options with "use system value" in the magento panel as well as the image below. I was wondering if these checked options are enabled and if the value that is in this input is the value that is being used?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Magento 2 defines the default values inside a configuration file.
namespace\modulename\etc\config.xml

You can open the relevant module's config.xml and check default values.

e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <sectionname>
                <groupname>
                    <fieldid>1</fieldid>
                </groupname>
            </sectionname>
        </default>
    </config>
```

System configuration system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <tab id="namespace_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
                <label>COnfig Title</label>
            </tab>
            <section id="sectionname" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
    showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Some Title</label>
                <tab>namespace_tab</tab>
                <resource>Namespace_Modulename::system_config</resource>
                <group id="groupname" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
    showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Some Configuration</label>
                    <field id="fieldid" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" 
    showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enable in frontend</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                 </group>   
            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

Comment: but are the default values ​​the same ones that are input blocked?

Comment: Yes. that's same as showing in disabled input

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!!